# Aligning right for the select attribute in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align one of the select attribute in html to the right side of the page. However i was unable to achieve it. I have attached my codes here.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Java Casting</h1>

    <h3>From</h3>
<h3 align="right">To</h3>
<select>
  <option value="int">int</option>
  <option value="double">double</option>
  <option value="long">long</option>
  <option value="String">String</option>
</select>
<select  align="right" >
  <option value="int">int</option>
  <option value="double">double</option>
  <option value="long">long</option>
  <option value="String">String</option>
</select>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are trying to achieve if i'm not mistaken.

```css
.right {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Java Casting</h1>

<div class="left">
  <h3>From</h3>
  <select>
    <option value="int">int</option>
    <option value="double">double</option>
    <option value="long">long</option>
    <option value="String">String</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <h3>To</h3>
  <select>
    <option value="int">int</option>
    <option value="double">double</option>
    <option value="long">long</option>
    <option value="String">String</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `<select style="float:right">`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Java Casting</h1>

    <h3>From</h3>
<h3 align="right">To</h3>
<select>
  <option value="int">int</option>
  <option value="double">double</option>
  <option value="long">long</option>
  <option value="String">String</option>
</select>
<select style="float:right">
  <option value="int">int</option>
  <option value="double">double</option>
  <option value="long">long</option>
  <option value="String">String</option>
</select>


</body>
</html>
```